# Displaylink driver installation fails on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, thinkpad, ideapad, displaylink

I have been trying to connect an extra monitor through the DVI port of ThinkPad USB 3 Pro docking station (which has a DisplayLink label) with a Lenovo IdeaPad L340 which has Ubuntu 18.04. All other drivers (sound, USBs) are working out of the box, but not the display.

I followed the installation steps for Ubuntu 18.04 driver Release: 5.1
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649

But that failed in the step of running the script:

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.1.26.run 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.1.26  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.1.26 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
WARNING: Version 1.7.0 of EVDI kernel module is already running.
Please reboot before attempting to re-install DisplayLink Linux Software.
Installation terminated.
```

After some googling; I did the following:

```
$ sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.1.26.run --keep --noexec

displaylink-driver-5.1.26$ sudo ./displaylink-installer.sh uninstall

DisplayLink Linux Software 5.1.26 install script called: uninstall
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Uninstalling
Removing EVDI from kernel tree, DKMS, and removing sources.
Stopping displaylink-driver systemd service
Failed to stop displaylink-driver.service: Unit displaylink-driver.service not loaded.
Failed to disable unit: Unit file displaylink-driver.service does not exist.
Removing suspend-resume hooks
Removing udev rule
Removing Core folder

Uninstallation steps complete.
Please note that the evdi kernel module is still in the memory.
A reboot is required to fully complete the uninstallation process.
```

It looks like the uninstall is not going through due to displaylink-driver.service does not exist. I rebooted several times; I even tried to run Ubuntu in console mode to avoid any issue with the X server.

Following the steps here to change the config of the X server did not help:
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades

Neither building DisplayLink / EVDI mentioned here helped:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/building-displaylink-evdi/73626

- lsusb command result:

```
$lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17ef:1017 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17e9:433f DisplayLink 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:1016 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 174f:1176 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:1017 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:1016 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- dkms status initially:

```
$dkms status
nvidia, 440.59, 5.3.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
```

- dkms status after building DisplayLink / EVDI

```
$ dkms status
evdi, devel, 5.3.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia, 440.59, 5.3.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
```

- Kernel version

```
$uname -a
Linux 5.3.0-59-generic #53~18.04.1-Ubuntu
```

I would appreciate any kind of help; please let me know if further information is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation is successful ... finally.

In case someone ran into the same issue; here is what I have done.
Not sure how did I fix it exactly, but I tried different approaches:

1. To install the drivers using this installer:
   https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian

I run the script displaylink-debian.sh and also the script evdi.sh which ended up with the same result, but it installed some more libs that might helped.

2. To remove evdi version which is already running

- I first stopped gdm3

```
sudo service gdm3 stop
```

- Then I ran the uninstall command again plus several other command using modprobe

```
sudo ./displaylink-installer.sh uninstall

modprobe -r evdi
modprobe -r evdi-1.6.0
```

After a reboot; installation went though (with the first command in the question) and the display was detected but was black; another reboot fixed the black screen.